# Tornado/Python error unable to comprehend

Tags: python, if-statement, tornado

I got a simple piece of code for playing around with the addition/subtraction of date/

```
def calculate(self, datemonthyear, add): #not handled the condition for years between 00 and 09.
        year = datemonthyear % 100
        datemonthyear = datemonthyear / 100
        date = datemonthyear % 100
        month = datemonthyear / 100
        leapyear = (year % 4 == 0 or year==0)
        print month
        print date
        print year
        print ((leapyear and date + add > 29) or (not(leapyear) and date + add > 28))
        if (month == 2 and ((leapyear and date + add > 29) or (not(leapyear) and date + add > 28))):
            print "1"
            return "301" + str(year)
        elif month == 3 and leapyear and date + add < 1:
            print "2"
            return "229" + str(year)
        elif month == 3 and not(leapyear) and date + add < 1:
            print "3"
            return "228" + str(year)
        elif month in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]:
            print "4"
            if month == 12 and date + add > 31:
                return "101" + str((year + 1)%100)
            elif month == 1 and date + add < 1:
                return "1231" + str((year - 1)%100)
            elif month == 8 and date + add < 1:
                return "731" + str(year)
            elif date + add > 31:
                return str(month + 1) + "01" + str(year)
            elif date + add < 1:
                return str(month - 1) + "30" + str(year)
        elif month in [2,4,6,9,11]:
            print "5"
            if date + add > 30:
                return str(month + 1) + "01" + str(year)
            elif date + add < 1:
                return str (month -1) + "31" + str(year)
        print "Has to come here"
        return str(month) + str(date + add) + str(year)
```

When i call

```
print "22820 " + self.calculate(22820, 1)
```

It throws up this error

```
E 120731 15:27:04 web:1064] Uncaught exception GET / (::1)
    HTTPRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8881', method='GET', uri='/', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1', body='', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'Host': 'localhost:8881', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19', 'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cookie': '_xsrf=2328f244ddf94402884f39490aeed347', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado-2.3-py2.7.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1021, in _execute
        getattr(self, self.request.method.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
      File "trends.py", line 33, in get
        print "22820 " + self.calculate(22820, 1)
    TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

This basically means calculate is returning None but I am not able to debug it

Comment: So basically all the dates between feb 1 and feb 28 (if leap yr) else till 27 are showing issues

Comment: Actually, copying and pasting your code in ipython and calling: `print "22820 " + calculate(None, 22820, 1)` correctly prints `22820 22920` for me. Can you paste a full script (with handlers) to highlight the problem?

Comment: For parsing dates, you could probably do better using `dateutil`: http://labix.org/python-dateutil/

Comment: Maybe some indentations are wrong and the last `return` is never called?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that when `month == 0` you miss all of the if statements and end up in the default return case for the function with is the value `None`.  You cannot concatenate a  string with the None value.

Comment: If `month == 0`, then the statements after `print "Has to come here"` will be executed.

Comment: Ooops, missed that indentation change.  However the error implies that the function is returning ``None``.  Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

Some observations that were too long for a comment:

I just want to confirm that this statement:

`print "22820 " + self.calculate(22820, 1)`

Needs to be called from within a method of the same class where you have `calculate` defined, and that the calling method, needs to be called from an instance of that class.

`not` is not a function, so `not(foo)` doesn't make any sense - unless you have your own version of a function called `not`, in which case you should rename it.